# How to Loop mapView.Annotations in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Having trouble converting this line of Objective C code to Swift

```
for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in mapView.annotations) {
    // Do Something
}
```

When I try:

```
for (annotation:MKannotation in mapView.annotations)
```

OR

```
for (annotation in mapView.annotations)
```

I get: ***Expected ';' in 'for' statement***

Thanks!!

Comment: what is your trouble? are you getting compilation errors? what have you tried?

Comment: Tried: `for (annotation:MKannotation in mapView.annotations)`

Comment: `for annotation in mapView.annotations { ... }`

Comment: @zisoft when I try your suggestion I get the same compilation error **Expected ';' in 'for' statement**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
for annotation in mapView.annotations as [MKAnnotation] {...}
```

Comment: This should be for annotation in mapView.annotations as! [MKAnnotation]

Comment: Also this should be marked as the correct answer :)